# How do I get rid of the pie chart outline in Perl's GD::Graph?

Tags: perl, graph, gd

I am trying to create a pie chart with no outline using [GD::Graph](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GD-Graph). Frustratingly I can control the colour of the outline with this:

```
    accentclr => 'black',
```

So I would expect that I could get rid of the outline completely by doing this:

```
    accentclr => undef,
```

However, when I do this the outline does disappear but the rest of the pie chart does as well with only the labels remaining!

Here's a simplified version of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use GD::Graph::pie;

# Data to be graphed: 1st array is labels, 2nd array is data
my @data = ( 
     ["1st","2nd","3rd","4th"],
     [ 1, 3.5, 5, 6 ],
  );
my $graph = GD::Graph::pie->new(400, 400);

$graph->set(      
#   accentclr   => undef,   
    '3d'            => 0,
) or die $graph->error;

my $gd = $graph->plot(\@data) or die $graph->error;

open(IMG, '>pie.png') or die $!;
binmode IMG;
print IMG $gd->png;
```

Comment: Why cant use the same color as your background?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set `accentclr` to `undef`.

From the [`GD:Graph`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm#COLOURS) documentation:

> bgclr, fgclr, boxclr, accentclr, shadowclr
>
> Drawing colours used for the chart: background, foreground (axes and grid), axis box fill colour, accents (bar, area and pie outlines), and shadow (currently only for bars).
>
> ***All colours should have a valid value*** as described in ["COLOURS"](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GDGraph/Graph.pm#COLOURS), ***except boxclr, which can be undefined***, in which case the box will not be filled.

It seems that your best option would be to set the `accentclr` value to be the same as `boxclr`.